# Should I populate a session variable from a cookie?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

I have a site with a login function, and a "Remember Me" option. In my users table I have a 128 digit random token which I put in the cookie, and then use to lookup the user.

I will be using a "LoggedInUser" which is an instance of my "User" class, which will be populated with a database lookup, so I can retrieve the users username, id, and other info. Now assuming the user has a cookie, should I simply perform a user lookup using the cookies value, or should I store the token in a session and perform the lookup with that? The main worries here are security and performance, IE which is more secure and which will have shorter load times?

Comment: Don't reinvent authentication systems. Use Identity.

Answer (score 0):

Session Id normally stored in cookie - so there is almost no security differences whether you store ID in cookie yourself or use SessionState cookie.

Same for performance - the main cost will bin in DB lookup, obviously if you do couple extra steps (add/red from session state) it will be (probably not measurably) faster.

Notes:

- "random" generated by session state went through plenty of security reviews, hopefully your one is as good too.
- Session State cookie is not marked as "secure" by default so will be sent over HTTP too, clearly yours will not be - so custom cookie a bit better.
- Session state can be configured cookieless, in your case your scheme is a bit safe (as you can't mistakenly share cookie, but urls are easy to share).